# Rewriting an ATM program to require two files

Tags: ruby

I've created an ATM program and would like to rewrite certain aspects of it to require two files, one containing the names on the accounts and the money information, the other containing the pin number information here's the current code for the working ATM:

```
class Account
  attr_reader :name, :checking_account, :savings_account, :transfer
  def initialize(name, checking_account, savings_account)
    @name = name
    @checking_account = checking_account
    @savings_account = savings_account
    @transfer = transfer
  end


  def pin
      @pin = '1234'
  end


  def display
    puts "Welcome back #{name} enter your PIN:"
    input = gets.chomp
    if input == pin
      main_menu
    else
      bad_pin
  end
end


def main_menu
  puts """
  Welcome back #{name}!
  Follow the instructions as follows:
  To display Balance press '1'
  To make a Withdrawl press '2'
  To make a Deposit press '3'
  To Transfer funds press '4'
  To exit the system press '5'
  """
  input = gets.chomp
  case input
  when '1'
    balance
  when '2'
    withdrawl
  when '3'
    deposit
  when '4'
    transfer
  else
    exit
  end
end


def balance
  puts "Which balance? Checking or Savings?"
  input = gets.chomp
  if input =~ /checking/i
    puts "Your balance for your Checking Account is: $#{checking_account}."
    main_menu
  elsif input =~ /savings/i
    puts "Your balance for your Savings Account is: $#{savings_account}."
    main_menu
  else
    main_menu
  end
end


def withdrawl
  puts "Please press '1' to make a withdrawl from checking. Press '2' to make a withdrawl from Savings. Press '3' to go back to the menu."
  input = gets.chomp
  case input
  when '1'
    puts "How much would you like to withdrawl?"
    input = gets.chomp!
    @checking_account -= input.to_f
    puts "You have withdrawn $#{input}; you now have $#{checking_account} in your checking. Thank you for using this ATM you will be redirected to the main menu."
    main_menu
  when '2'
    puts "How much would you like to withdraw?"
    input = gets.chomp!
    @savings_account -= input.to_f
    puts "You have withdrawn ${input}; you now have $#{savings_account} in your savings. Thank you for using this ATM you will be redirected to the main menu"
    main_menu
  else
    main_menu
  end
end


def deposit
  puts "Which account would you like to deposit into: Checkings(1), or Savings(2)?"
  input = gets.chomp
  if input == '1'
    puts "Enter amount to deposit: "
    amount = gets.chomp!
    @checking_account += amount.to_f
    puts "You have made a depost of $#{amount} leaving you with $#{checking_account}. Thank you for using this ATM. You will be redirected to the main menu."
    main_menu
  elsif input == '2'
    puts "Enter amount to deposit: "
    amount = gets.chomp!
    @savings_account += amount.to_f
    puts "You have made a deposit of $#{amount} leaving you with $#{savings_account}. Thank you for using this ATM. You will be redirected to the main menu."
    main_menu
  else
    main_menu
  end
end


def transfer 
  puts "Would you like to transfer funds from Checking(1) or Savings(2)?"
  input = gets.chomp
  if input == '1'
    puts "Enter amount to transfer from Checking to Savings: Current balance #{checking_account}."
    amount = gets.chomp
    @checking_account -= amount.to_f
    @savings_account += amount.to_f
    puts "You have successfully transfered #{amount} from your Checking account new balance: #{checking_account}. Savings balance: #{savings_account}. You will be redirected to the main menu."
    main_menu
  elsif input == '2'
    puts "Enter amount to transfer from Savings to Checking: Current balance #{savings_account}."
    amount = gets.chomp
    @savings_account -= amount.to_f
    @checking_account += amount.to_f
    puts "You have succesfully transfered #{amount} from your Savings account new balance: #{savings_account}. Checking account balance: #{checking_account}. You will be redirected to the main menu."
    main_menu
  else
    puts "Invalid entry"
    exit
  end
end


def bad_pin
  puts "Access Denied: incorrect PIN"
    exit
  end
end

my_account = Account.new("Thomas", 500_000, 750_000)
my_account.display
```

What I want to do is use two separate files, `names.text` and `pins.text` one holding the account names and the accounts information(names.txt), the other holding the pin numbers of the account(pins.txt).

names.text I.E.:

```
my_account = Account.new("Thomas", 500_000, 750_000)
my_account.display

my_account2 = Account.new("Jake", 50_000, 50_000)    
my_account.display

my_account3 = Account.new("Anothername", 10, 50)
my_account.display
```

The file with the pin numbers(pins.txt) I think would look something like this(if not please enlighten me):

```
my_account @pin = 1234
my_account2 @pin = 2345
my_account3 @pin = 3456
```

So my questions are:

- Where would I need to rewrite this code in order to acquire the information from the files, apart from the obvious `pin` method.
- Would I need to use `require` or `require_relative`?

Comment: How are you associating the Account with the PIN? 2 separate files will need more of an identifier unless you plan on using index. Since this is clearly just a conceptual thing where security is not a concern and you aren't using a database i would actually recommend YAML over text files as it can be easily loaded parsed and updated. [YAML::Store](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html) or [YAML::DBM](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/DBM.html) would probably be of some use to you.

Comment: What do you mean by associating the account with the pin? I'll look into YAML thank you.

Comment: I've looked into it and I'd much rather require it from a file. I really need to practice doing that.

Comment: Okay then back to my original question how do you intend on associating an Account with a Pin will it be based on the line of the file because based on your current example the accounts file is not needed since you are storing account information in the pin file anyway

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out, I want to be able to call different accounts based on the pin that is given, but I also want the pin to be stored away from the account information. I'm guessing from my examples, that's how I would store the information for the pins but I don't know..